# Prove that $\mu^*(\limsup_n P_n ) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Here is the problem: Let ${f_{n} : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$ be a sequence of real valued measurable functions and let $E$ be a measurable set. Assume that $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow 0$. Define $P_{n} = \{ x \in E : |f_n(x)| > \epsilon\}$. Show that $\mu^*(\limsup_n P_n ) = 0$.

Well the first thing I want to come up is a countable union or intersection. By definition,

$$\limsup_n P_{n} = \cap_{n= 1}^{\infty} \cup_{k = n}^{\infty} P_k .$$ I am not sure how to get the countable union or intersection of sets. I am not sure what to do here. Can you give me only hints please?

Comment: Is $\mu^*$ an outer measure or a measure? (Not that it matters.)

Comment: Note that $\limsup_n P_n = \emptyset$ as each $x$ can only be in finitely many $P_n$.

Comment: Yeah it is the outer measure. Also is x  in infinitely many $P_n$?

Comment: How can any $x$ be in $P_n$ io?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Read my second comment again. It's hard to type on the phone.

Comment: So could I show that each $P_n$ are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: In general the $P_n$ are **not** pairwise disjoint.

Comment: I just realized what you mean a few seconds ago. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added an answer detailing what I meant.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask another question? If $\mu^* (E) < \infty $, how can I show $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu^*(P_n) = 0? $

Comment: Why are you using the outer measure? All sets here are measurable.

Comment: I mean $\mu$ sorry about that

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f_n(x) \to 0$, each $x$ can only be in a finite number of $P_n$ (since there is some $N$ such that for $k \ge N$ we have $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$.)

Hence for each $x$ there is some $N$ such that $x \notin P_n$ for all $k \ge N$.

That is, for each $x$ there is some $N$ such that $x \notin \cup_{k \ge N} P_k$.

Continuing, this means for all $x$, $x \notin \cap_N \cup_{k \ge N} P_k$.

In particular, $\cap_N \cup_{k \ge N} P_k = \emptyset$ and since $\mu^* \emptyset = 0$
we have the desired result.